# <video> autoplay not always working with Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

Im building a new webpage with video background. The problem is that Firefox is the only browser that have problem with html5 autoplaying. If page was loaded atleast one time the video is working correclty, starts right after the page load automatically but.. if page is loaded for the first time in most cases the video in background doesn't start and show something like TV's snow.

Facts:
- I don't think its 'video' tag (tried many configurations thinking it might help),
- I'm also sure its not problem with video file - tried few videos,
- tried all formats - it happens with all of them: mp4, wemb, ogg, All at the same time and individually,
- it's not problem with my PC - been trying on windows, mac and linux,
- Its not plugin - i don't use any with FF.

Check it out here: http://strona5.nanit.webd.pl Just do it in private session and close window after every load so you'll see that its lottery.

Regards.

Comment: worked fine for me .. FF vsn 46 on windows

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on FF 47 Linux. Have you tried with a simple page that has just the video element and see if that works?